# How to fix FileNotFoundError in file moving script when it reads the filenames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil, pathlib

My Python script reads the first two characters of a file, makes a folder named those first two characters, then makes a subfolder named the 3rd and 4th characters.  Then it copies the file to two subfolders of the subfolder called image, and thumb.  But even though it is reading the file names in correctly, it is raising a `FileNotFoundError` when I try to use `shutil.copy()`.

```
import shutil
import os
from pathlib import Path

assets_path = Path("/Users/Jackson Clark/Desktop/uploads")
export_path = Path("/Users/Jackson Clark/Desktop/uploads")

source = os.listdir(assets_path)

'''
NOTE: Filters.js is the important file
The logic:
    - Go through each file in the assets_path directory
    - Rename the files to start with RoCode (this could be a seperate script)
    - Create a new directory with the first four characters of the files name
    - Create two sub directories with the names 'image' and 'thumb'
    - Copy the file to both the 'image' and 'thumb' directories
    That should be all, but who knows tbh
Good links:
    - https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/os/python-the-shutil-module
    - https://stackabuse.com/creating-and-deleting-directories-with-python/
'''
for f in source:
    f_string = str(f)
    folder_one_name = f_string[0:2]
    folder_two_name = f_string[2:4]

    path_to_export_one = os.path.join(export_path, folder_one_name)
    path_to_export_two = os.path.join(export_path, folder_one_name,
                                      folder_two_name)

    try: 
        os.mkdir(path_to_export_one)
        os.mkdir(path_to_export_two)
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(path_to_export_two, "image"))
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(path_to_export_two, "thumb"))
        shutil.copy(f, os.path.join(path_to_export_two, "image"))
        shutil.copy(f, os.path.join(path_to_export_two, "thumb"))
    except FileExistsError as err:
        try:
            shutil.copy(f, os.path.join(path_to_export_two, "image"))
            shutil.copy(f, os.path.join(path_to_export_two, "thumb"))
        except FileNotFoundError as err:
            print("FileNotFoundError2 on " + f + " file")
    except FileNotFoundError as err:
        print("FileNotFoundError1 on " + f + " file")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `f` you are using is a simple string like `"readme.txt"`.  This is because `os.listdir()` returns a list of the entries of the given directory, each entry is just the name *in* this directory (not a full path).  Your script probably isn't run in this directory, so accessing `readme.txt` doesn't work.

I suggest to simply prepend the path `f` is in.

Btw, the `Path` objects from `pathlib` know the operator `/`, so you can write your code in a more readable fashion like this:

```
path_to_export_one = export_path / folder_one_name
path_to_export_two = path_to_export_one / folder_two_name
...
f_path = assets_path / f
...
shutil.copy(f_path, path_to_export_two / 'image')
```